# Check if user is in role or not nestedly?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, roles

Is there any way to check if user is in particular role nested? e.g.

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin"){

  <div class="div1"> </div>

  @if(User.IsInRole("AdminAssitant"){
     <div class="div2"> </div>
  }

}
```

What I mean is I want to show both `divs` if user is `Admin`, otherwise show only `div2`. I don't want to create like this:

```
@if(User.IsInRole("Admin"){

  <div class="div1"> </div>
  <div class="div2"> </div>
}

 @if(User.IsInRole("AdminAssitant"){
   <div class="div2"> </div>
 }
```

Because it is just a sample I have very complex scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roles aren't really designed to be nested. This is usually due to a misinterpretation of what a "role" is. Strictly speaking a role is merely a privilege: things like `CanEdit`, `CanDelete`, etc. They're supposed to be built up. So for example an "Admin" is simply a user with a set of all available roles. Creating an actual `Admin` role is merely shortcut to imply membership in every other role, simply because you might occasionally neglect to assign a new role in the system to every single "Admin" user.

Speaking in the context of something like `Admin` and `AdminAssistant`, you're in the realm of *group* membership, and groups *are* hierarchical in nature. A group can be part of another group and privilege flows down through all the levels.

Getting back to your actual problem here, you simply need to model the hierarchy because there's no way to actually *impose* that hierarchy on the roles. That essentially means doing something like:

```
@if (User.IsInRole("Admin") || User.IsInRole("AdminAssistant")) {

    <div class="div1"> </div>

    @if (User.IsInRole("AdminAssistant")) {
        <div class="div2"> </div>
    }
}
```

That way, either role will get div1, but only `AdminAssistant` will get div2.

Answer (score 0):

Because it is nested, if the role is not admin, then the AssistantAdmin statement is never checked. Therefore you will not be able to complete a nested check exactly like that.

Comment: His question is dealing with role based hierarchy. His example is hypothetical and not "why is this not working"

Answer (score 0):

RolePrincipal.IsInRole Method does not give you ability to creep up or down the role hierarchy. You could use RolePrincipal.GetRoles to get an array of all roles the user belongs and possibly write your security around if the role is present in that array.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.roleprincipal.getroles(v=vs.110).aspx

Very interested on how others would approach this.

Example in your View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Example";
    string[] roles = ((RolePrincipal)User).GetRoles();
}

@if (roles.Contains("Admin"))
{
    <div class="div1">Weeee</div>
    if (roles.Contains("AdminAssitant"))
    {
        <div class="div2">Whoooa</div>
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there any way to tackle this problem?

Comment: You could do something like so in your view:      
       @{
            ViewBag.Title = "Example";

            RolePrincipal rp = (RolePrincipal)User;
            string[] roles = rp.GetRoles();
    
    
        }

        @if (roles.Contains("Admin"))
        {
            <div class="div1">Weeee</div>
            if (roles.Contains("AdminAssitant"))
            {
                <div class="div2">Whoooa</div>
            }
        }